# Remove lines from a file between lines matching a pattern

Tags: linux, pcre

If this is my file:

```
This part can stay
START ALPHA
This should be deleted
And this too
END ALPHA
This should stay
START BETA
This should be deleted
END BETA
This should stay
```

Everything between the "START (whatever)" and "END (whatever)" lines should be deleted.

How can I do this?  I'm can use sed, perl, python, whatever works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an `ed(1)` or `sed(1)` script:

```
$ cat filter.sh
#!/bin/sh
exec sed "/START $1/,/END $1/d" data.txt
$ filter.sh ALPHA
This part can stay
This should stay
START BETA
This should be deleted
END BETA
This should stay
$ filter.sh BETA
This part can stay
START ALPHA
This should be deleted
And this too
END ALPHA
This should stay
This should stay
$ _
```

the `$` sign is the shell prompt, I think you'll understand.  `filter.sh` is the script that does what you want.